# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, menus

I have just updated to the wordpress laest version. And this message is showing on the homepage.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/jafa9363696/public_html/xn--9dba0af7bd.com/wp-includes/nav-menu.php
>   on line 727 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/jafa9363696/public_html/xn--9dba0af7bd.com/wp-includes/nav-menu.php
>   on line 731

This is from line 723-732

```
$menu_item->url = get_permalink( $menu_item->object_id );
$original_object = get_post( $menu_item->object_id );
/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
$original_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $original_object->post_title, $original_object->ID );
if ( '' === $original_title ) {
    /* translators: %d: ID of a post */
    $original_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $original_object->ID );
}
```

Comment: What are the original contents of `$menu_item` and `original_object`? These are the important ones.

Comment: This is the website http://שומרון.com/ in English http://realestate.bidgates.com/ ,,, used real estate theme,,, I am not good at php

Answer (score 1):

This code tries to retrieve a post instance, but it is failing for some reason.

On top of my head I don’t think this should ever happen within normal operation of menus. I would suspect that menu structure is somehow corrupt.

Without diving into development side of it, an attempt of easy fix might be examining menu in admin and maybe removing entries which appear invalid and/or trying to re–save it.